# laravel 5 - use Auth::check() in RouteServiceProvider.php

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, service-provider

I want to check for unread messages in my app like it was in the "before filter" in laravel 4. I have put this into the boot function in the `RouteServiceProvider.php` file:

```
$unread_messages = 0;

if(Auth::check())
{
    $unread_messages = Message::where('owner',Auth::user()->id)
                                ->where('read',0)
                                ->count();
}

View::share('unread_messages',$unread_messages);
```

It seems, I can't use `Auth::check()` there. I am logged in, but the code inside the if clause is not used. The app is named and I have a `use Auth;` in the top of the file. Is this generally not possible in this file, or must it be an error that i have made?

Comment: Why don't you add this within your `app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php` class with the constructor, that way all subsequent controllers will run the code and the data will be available in all views. Be sure to call it via `parent::__construct();`

Comment: i have added `public function __construct(){ .. }` after `use DispatchesCommands, ValidatesRequests;` in the `abstract class Controller`.. it seems to work but I am not sure if it is the right way. where should i call it with `parent::__contruct();` ? i don't understand.

Comment: Well it is definitely not relevant to the `RouteServiceProvider`, so it should not reside in there. I think it is relevant more towards setting up the data for the views, which is for the controllers to do. Put `parent::__contruct();` within the `__construct()`.You can either use this method or use a view composer, on your base blade layout.

Comment: ok , i have put the `parent::__construct()` into the `__construct()` of controllers, which have a `__construct()` and `extend` `Controller` except `Auth/PasswordController.php` because I am not sure.. thank you.

Comment: Well the Auth/* Controllers are used when the user is not logged in. So they are not required to have this information.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it as a Middleware, and add to `App\Http\Kernel::$middleware` array (after `Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession`).

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory;

class UnreadMessages 
{
    protected $auth;
    protected $view;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth, Factory $view)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $unread = 0;
        $user = $this->auth->user();

        if (! is_null($user)) {
            $unread = Message::where('user_id', $user->id)
                          ->where('read', 0)
                          ->count();
        }

        $this->view->share('unread_messages', $unread);

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Further read http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware

Comment: This worked well for me as a god strategy for loading data on every view in a controller.